# E: Unable to correct dependencies

Tags: apt, dependencies

I can't install any software on Ubuntu 18.04. 
I'm facing some error like:

```
Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages
```

Output of `sudo apt --fix-broken install`:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
Correcting dependencies... failed. 
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
dbconfig-mysql : Depends: default-mysql-client but it is not installed or virtual-mysql-client 
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages. 
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What do you get if you try to install `default-mysql-client`? Paste the output of `sudo apt install default-mysql-client`.

Answer (score 0):

just execute the command:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Comment: I have already tried this.
After applied this, 
Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

Comment: I can propose you to remove the package (apt remove package_name) and install it again.